# How to use variables in a VBA code using the sumif function

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, sumifs

I download a data set that always has a different number of rows. I store two columns as variables, the imports and the months. Then I need to run a `Sumif` formula that sums the value of imports by the months. I am writing a `Sumif` formula that uses the two variables and references the cell to its left.

The cells however vary in location based on the changing size of the data set. So I write a code to select the last active cell on a column and select the cell 3 rows down.

When writing the formula with the variables and the cell its giving me an error. Please help sorry for any typos fist time doing this.

I select all the active cells in range D and store  them as months, I do the same for the imports. Then using range I find the last active cell on  column M, and use select the cell 3 rows down, where I wish to write my formula.

Please see my codes to see what am I doing wrong, I am a novice coder.

```
Sub Importaciones()
'
' Importaciones Macro
'




    Dim LastRow As Long

        LastRow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 

    Dim Months As Long

        Months = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown)).Select

    Dim Imports As Long

        Imports = Range("M2", Range("M2").End(xlDown)).Select

     Dim LastRowM As Long

      LastRowM = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

      Range("M" & LastRowM + 3).Formula = "=sumif(" & Months & ", " & 
      Range("L" & LastRow + 3) & ", " & Imports & ")"

End Sub
```

For the formula to work and the sum of the month that I choose comes up

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of at least one other question that I can't find at the moment, but the answer is exactly what you're already doing with `"M" & Rows.Count`. i.e. something like `"=sumif(" & Months & ", " & Range("L" & LastRow + 3) & ", " & Imports & ")"`

Comment: If its a dupllicate can you show me the link for the question I am allegedley duplicating?

Comment: The link is at the top of the post; nothing wrong with asking a duplicate question, it happens all the time - note that I've also provided you with a more personalized solution.

Comment: Thanks, however after reading the post you linked and you copying the solution you offered its still not working. Any other tips  `Range("M" & LastRowM + 3).Formula = "=sumif(" & Months & ", " & Range("L" & LastRow + 3) & ", " & Imports & ")" `

Comment: You will want to declare Months and Imports as Ranges and set them without the `.Select` on the end.  You will then want to use `Months.Address(0,0)` and `Imports.Address(0,0)` in the formula @MathieuGuindon provided.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've reopened the post, feel free to post that as an answer :)

Comment: @ScottCraner  Doing that makes my formula that work either  `Dim Months As Range

        Months = Range("D2", Range("D2").End(xlDown))` is this correct?

Comment: @Myrnaloy - You need to `Set Months = ...` since it's a `Range` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per all the comments:

```
Sub Importaciones()

    With Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet
        Dim LastRow As Long
            LastRow = .Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim Months As Range
            Set Months = .Range("D2", .Range("D2").End(xlDown))

        Dim Imports As Range
            Set Imports = .Range("M2", .Range("M2").End(xlDown))

         Dim LastRowM As Long
            LastRowM = .Range("M" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

            .Range("M" & LastRowM + 3).Formula = "=sumif(" & Months.Address(0, 0) & ", " & .Range("L" & LastRow + 3).Address(0, 0) & ", " & Imports.Address(0, 0) & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```